# NSLOOKUP returning 2 IP Address

Tags: nslookup

When I do nslookup, it is returning my own DNS and the IP address of the server that I'm doing nslookup.  How can I avoid it printing my own DNS server?

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (servers.txt) do nslookup %%A >>ips.txt
```

Comment: Your question is unclear... You would need to give more detailed information showing a screenshot or something for us to understand exactly what you trying the problem and explain what you are trying to accomplish since your "script" is less than clear.

Comment: `nslookup` is just not a suitable tool for what you’re trying to achieve. You’ll probably have more luck with PowerShell. Also keep in mind that a single domain name can have any number of `A` and `AAAA` records.

Answer (score 1):

Use a second stacked `For /f` to parse nslookup output and skip the first three lines:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /f "tokens=*" %%A in (
  servers.txt
) Do For /f "Skip=3 Tokens=1* Delims=: " %%B in (
  'nslookup %%A'
) Do Echo %%B=%%C
```

Sample Output

```
Name=Matar.fritz.box
Addresses=2003:dc:73c5:7800::0
        =192.168.3.92
```

Depending on your setup nslookup could return more than one IP, even including IPv6 addresses. So going for IPv4 with Ping could be easier:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /f "tokens=*" %%A in (
  servers.txt
) Do For /f "tokens=2Delims=[]" %%B in (
  'Ping -4 -n 1 %%A ^|find "["'
) Do Echo IPv4=%%B
```

---

```
IPv4=192.168.192.92
```